# Is it good idea to store sensitive info in firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my Android application I have an idea to store in database some serial key. If user enters correct key he gets full version of application and the key is disabled on the server to avoid multiply usage of the same key, otherwise he can buy app in Google Play without a key.

For this I thought to use Firebase Database but after read this I have some doubts

> Firebase Realtime Database
>
> Store and sync data with our NoSQL cloud database. Data is synced across all clients in realtime, and remains available when your app goes offline.

Does it mean that firebase will duplicate the table with all available keys to all application users and some smart user can read the list from this copy at his phone?

Comment: I'd like to add that I don't think storing sensitive information is a good use case for realtime; instead use firestore.

Answer (score 5):

Not all data is automatically duplicated to all clients. Only data that the client subscribes to is received by that client.

You can control what data each client can see through [Firebase's server-side security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/). For example, you'll typically want to [ensure that each user can only read their own data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security).

Answer (score 2):

It probably isn't a good idea to store super-sensitive data like social security numbers or credit card numbers, but if you see https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/ you can see, that you can control access to data, & use validation, especially since you can regenerate the keys if they become compromised, it wouldn't be the worst option.  If you look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security you can see, that it's possible to write an app that uses it like google drive with a smartphone-based client.

Comment: If you need to store personal details. Store a combined hash of all of those rather than the raw details.

Comment: @Liam Then the user would have to re-enter all of it for it to validate(that would make sense if you need a certain set of info. to reset your account).

Answer (score 0):

Personally the answer would no. You may want to think about [Google Play Subscriptions and In-App Purchases](https://developer.android.com/google/play/developer-api#subscriptions_api_overview).

If you really have to then:

- Create a key as a user buys the upgrade (server-side).
- Store the device id/account id (**hashed**) and timestamp with the key.

Credit card details and expiry dates should be combined into one hash.

**Just encrypt everything**.

It's better to have a banned list than a list of approved key. Eventually you have to create more keys and it's easier just to maintain a list of banned keys.